# NTP failed to synchronize time

Tags: 16.04, ntp

I have Ubuntu Server 16.04 running on OpenVZ (VPS hosting provider), and I have difficulties running ntp for time synchronization. I just installed ntp (`apt install ntp`), but when I try it, I see

```
root@vps:~# ntpq -p
ntpq: read: Connection refused
```

My local time zone is correct

```
root@vps:~# dpkg-reconfigure tzdata    
Current default time zone: 'Europe/Prague'
Local time is now:      Mon May  9 08:40:44 CEST 2016.
Universal Time is now:  Mon May  9 06:40:44 UTC 2016.
```

When I try to reload ntp service `systemctl reload ntp.service`

```
Failed to reload ntp.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit ntp.service.
See system logs and 'systemctl status ntp.service' for details.
```

And when I run `systemctl status ntp.service`

```
ntp.service - LSB: Start NTP daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ntp; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Mon 2016-05-09 09:04:29 CEST; 8min ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 25429 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/ntp stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 25487 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/ntp start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 09 09:04:29 vps systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start NTP daemon.
May 09 09:04:29 vps ntpd[25496]: proto: precision = 0.092 usec (-23)
May 09 09:04:29 vps ntpd[25496]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
May 09 09:04:29 vps ntpd[25496]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
May 09 09:04:29 vps ntpd[25496]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
May 09 09:04:29 vps ntpd[25496]: Listen normally on 3 venet0 127.0.0.2:123
May 09 09:04:29 vps ntpd[25496]: Listen normally on 4 venet0:0 myipv4:123
May 09 09:04:29 vps ntpd[25496]: Listen normally on 5 lo [::1]:123
May 09 09:04:29 vps ntpd[25496]: Listen normally on 6 venet0 [myipv6]:123
May 09 09:04:29 vps ntpd[25496]: Listening on routing socket on fd #23 for interface updates
```

And in /var/log/syslog

```
May  9 09:04:29 vps ntpd[25496]: Listening on routing socket on fd #23 for interface updates
May  9 09:04:29 vps ntpd[25496]: start_kern_loop: ntp_loopfilter.c line 1126: ntp_adjtime: Operation not permitted
May  9 09:04:29 vps ntpd[25496]: set_freq: ntp_loopfilter.c line 1089: ntp_adjtime: Operation not permitted
May  9 09:04:29 vps ntpd[25496]: cap_set_proc() failed to drop root privs: Operation not permitted
```

I also tried

```
root@vps:~# ntpdate pool.ntp.org
9 May 09:19:47 ntpdate[25785]: Can't adjust the time of day: Operation not permitted
```

Does anybody know what's wrong with my NTP?

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if there is some conflict with `timedatectl`, the default in 16.04. What do you get for `timedatectl status`? The [Ubuntu Serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html) is not up to date with these changes for 16.04, but there is a pending [merge proposal](https://code.launchpad.net/~paelzer/serverguide/serverguide-16.04-fix-time-sync/+merge/294038) with updates.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably due to the fact that you are running ntp in a unprivileged container. OpenVZ is another project for containers, but like the others it share the same kernel between the host and the guests. And as the kernel maintain the time, it would be not acceptable for a VPS host that one container can change the kernel time, because that would impact all other container.

So there is not solution to your problem. If you find that the time reported inside your OpenVZ container is incorrect, you need to open a support ticket with your VPS host provider. They have to install ntpd on their host and make sure it is correctly synchronised.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a conflict with ntpdate being on the machine as well. If you ONLY install ntp but not ntpdate, then ntp is allowed to work. With both on the machine, ntp won't stay up on next reboot.

Seems related to this [bug](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs%40lists.ubuntu.com/msg4946115.html).

Comment: I started with just ntp installed and the problem was exactly the same. But I discussed it with the hosting provider and he told me that it should not work because changing time is not allowed on OpenVZ because it's built in to the hypervisor and virtual machines takes the time from hypervisor and I should take care only of right time zone settings on my VPS.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my ntp pool member list and restarted my ntp service. It worked for me.

server 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org

@ubuntu:/etc$ sudo  service ntp restart
 * Stopping NTP server ntpd

- Starting NTP server ntpd                                                                                   [ OK ]
  @ubuntu:/etc$ ntpq -p

  ## remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter

  ntp.ubuntu.com  .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
  *ntp.nexcess.net 142.66.101.13    2 u    8   64    1   28.094   -6.892   0.000
  propjet.latt.ne 44.24.199.34     3 u    6   64    1  141.591   14.905   0.000
  barry.tsi.io    198.60.22.240    2 u    7   64    1   91.846    0.492   0.000
  ntp1.wiktel.com 216.218.254.202  2 u    6   64    1   44.371  -10.567   0.000
  chilipepper.can 140.203.204.77   2 u    7   64    1   97.269   -6.298   0.000
  juniperberry.ca 145.238.203.14   2 u    7   64    1   98.729   -9.011   0.000
  golem.canonical 145.238.203.14   2 u    6   64    1  104.873  -11.536   0.000
  alphyn.canonica 132.246.11.231   2 u    1   64    1   35.188   -6.797   0.000

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, but I have the issue and following the answer of  user542049 I did:

```
sudo apt remove ntpdate
```

Suddenly with no reboot required, the clock matched the correct hour.